# What does j8傻逼 mean?

Tags: meaning, slang, internet-slang

In the following picture:

[image]

I understand the meaning of 傻逼 but what is the "j8" before it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to [chinaSMACK](https://www.chinasmack.com/glossary#J8), j8 is equivalent to 'penis' or any of its vulgar forms:

<sub>(rude language hidden behind spoiler, hover over or click to show)</sub>

> 鸡巴
>  jībā
>  *noun/adjective*.
>
>  Penis, dick, cock. When used as an adjective, it may mean “cocky”, “arrogant”, or a more generalized “fuck” or “damn”.

Answer (score 6):

J8 == ji 8 == ji ba == 鸡巴(penis).

In this case, the usage of j 8 is like 他妈，but the severity of the rudeness/vulgarity has been largely enhanced. 跟他妈傻逼一样 denotes the same meaning, but less vulgar.

So, never ever say it. It's really bad.

Answer (score 2):

That means "dick asshole". The domestic people are very disgusted with the policy of preferential treatment for international students.