# Is "JJ" slang for "penis" in Chinese?

Tags: slang, internet-slang

Reading the comments to the news article [巴西女排变性球星将竞选国会议员 已瞄准东京奥运](http://sports.sina.com.cn/others/volleyball/2018-09-28/doc-ihkmwytp6392402.shtml) about a Brazilian volleyballer who is transgender and wants to play in the Olympics, we have two comments:

> [image]

Both use this term "JJ".

> 男队员割了JJ就可以参加女队的比赛？真是天下大乱了！
> Can a male player cut a JJ to participate in a women's team? It’s really a mess! ([Google Translate](https://translate.google.cn/#zh-CN/en/%E7%94%B7%E9%98%9F%E5%91%98%E5%89%B2%E4%BA%86JJ%E5%B0%B1%E5%8F%AF%E4%BB%A5%E5%8F%82%E5%8A%A0%E5%A5%B3%E9%98%9F%E7%9A%84%E6%AF%94%E8%B5%9B%EF%BC%9F%E7%9C%9F%E6%98%AF%E5%A4%A9%E4%B8%8B%E5%A4%A7%E4%B9%B1%E4%BA%86%EF%BC%81))
>
> 隔了jj就可以参加女性的比赛，这对女性体育运动公平吗？
> You can participate in women's competitions after jj. Is this fair for women's sports? ([Google Translate](https://translate.google.cn/#zh-CN/en/%E9%9A%94%E4%BA%86jj%E5%B0%B1%E5%8F%AF%E4%BB%A5%E5%8F%82%E5%8A%A0%E5%A5%B3%E6%80%A7%E7%9A%84%E6%AF%94%E8%B5%9B%EF%BC%8C%E8%BF%99%E5%AF%B9%E5%A5%B3%E6%80%A7%E4%BD%93%E8%82%B2%E8%BF%90%E5%8A%A8%E5%85%AC%E5%B9%B3%E5%90%97%EF%BC%9F))

Here we have "[割](http://youdao.com/w/%E9%9A%94)了JJ" (gēle JJ; "cut JJ") and "[隔](http://youdao.com/w/%E9%9A%94)了jj" (géle JJ; "separate JJ"), which suggests it's most likely that JJ refers to "penis", but I'm not sure, so...

**Question**: Is "JJ" slang for "penis" in Chinese?

Comment: Yes, it comes from the pinyin JiJi. BTW I think 隔 is just a typo of 割.

Comment: Related [What does j8傻逼 mean?](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/30731/what-does-j8%E5%82%BB%E9%80%BC-mean)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Mandarin 雞巴/Jībā/ is slang for 'penis', And it is often further nicknamed 雞雞/jī jī/ or 小雞雞/Xiǎo Jī Jī/

JJ is a shorthand for 雞雞/Jī Jī/

~

A possibility for Cantonese to also use jj for penis:

*In Cantonese, we call children's (or small) penis 賓周
Since 周 sounded like 啫, we also call it 啫啫 or 啫啫仔
JJ sounded like 啫啫, therefore is used instead in some casual Cantonese publication, mostly entertainment news or gossip column.*

*As for adult (or big) penis, there are several different names for it.*

Comment: It's also possible that the proper writing for `ji1` is `㞓`.